# Magento Database import to new Database

Tags: database, importexport, export

trying to dump my cms_block and cms_page tables to new working Database. I get the Duplicate Entry for Primary Key ...what is the best way to go about this? when I export tables from old db I have Disable foreign key checks as well.

Comment: it doesn't make any sense - even when i dump just data only no structure, i still get the same Duplicate entry '5' for key 'PRIMARY'

Comment: In the new database, did you truncate those tables before importing? Something is getting caught up.

Comment: I cannot truncate a due to primary key

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood you just need CMS contents to be migrated.

It is not a good idea to inject data in you DB coming from another installation, you can really break something.

Just remeber the two rules of the Magento Fight Club: Never change the core and never inject your DB ;)

Why don't you use an import/export module like this: 
https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/export-import-cms-pages-blocks.html

I think it would be a safer method.

I did not try it, but I think it will fit your needings.